# Bluetooth activation problem on acer 5742G

Tags: bluetooth

I have an acer 5742G laptop which has a bluetooth inbuilt (I have used it in windows). The problem is the company has given only one button to activate wifi and bluetooth (fn+f3). In windows you press it once and a dialog box shows up with options to enable bluetooth or wifi. But in ubuntu nothing of that sort happens and it just toggles the wifi. What do I do to start my bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1667631):

> There are two files in `/lib/firmware/` folder. One is `ath3k-1.fw` and the other is `ath3k-2.fw`. Rename the first into something else and the second `ath3k-1.fw`. That fixed the bluetooth issue for me. So for example:
>
> - ath3k-1.fw -> ath3k-1b.fw
> - ath3k-2.fw -> ath3k-1.fw